# Separating low slope and high slope values from moderation dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a moderator variable where there is significant interaction. I am using the following data to achieve that. But looking at the scatter plot, all the blues and reds are clearly separated. I need to have a mix of these values but still achieve significant interaction. I used the ratio of outcome and predictor to separate the values but I know it is not right. Any ideas?

```r
set.seed(123)
predictor <- rnorm(200, 3.5, 2)
outcome <- c(0.9*predictor + rnorm(100, 3) - rnorm(100, 2)^1)
df = data.frame(predictor, outcome)

df$ratio = df$outcome/df$predictor
df = subset(df, !rowSums(df < 0))
df$moderator = ifelse(df$ratio > 1.3, "H", "L")
summary(lm(outcome ~ predictor, data = df))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = outcome ~ predictor, data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -4.2889 -0.9304 -0.1130  0.8753  3.4161 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  1.32910    0.21886   6.073 6.61e-09 ***
#> predictor    0.86324    0.05457  15.819  < 2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.385 on 192 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.5658, Adjusted R-squared:  0.5636 
#> F-statistic: 250.2 on 1 and 192 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

ggformula::gf_point(outcome ~ predictor, color = ~ moderator, data = df) +
  ggplot2::geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The [faux](https://debruine.github.io/faux/) package may be useful.